# Split a DataTable into 2 or more DataTables based on Column value

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, datatable

I have a DataTable called "DTHead" which has the following records,

```
 MIVID      Quantity         Value
------     ----------       --------
   1           10             3000
   1           20             3500
   1           15             2000
   2           20             3000
   2           50             7500
   3           25             2000
```

Here, I need to split the above DataTable into three tables based on the MIVID such as follows;

DTChild1:

```
  MIVID           Quantity        Value
 -------         ----------     ---------
   1                10             3000
   1                20             3500
   1                15             2000
```

DTChild2:

```
  MIVID           Quantity        Value
 -------         ----------     ---------
   2                20             3000
   2                50             7500
```

DTChild3:

```
  MIVID           Quantity        Value
 -------         ----------     ---------
    3               25             2000
```

Suppose, if the Header DataTable contains 4 different MIVID means, then 4 Child DataTable should be created based on the MIVID. How to do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `LINQ to DataTable` to group the first column by `GroupBy`, and use method [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx) to copy list of rows to `DataTable`

```
 List<DataTable> result = DTHead.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("MIVID"))
            .Select(g => g.CopyToDataTable())
            .ToList();
```

Then you can get the result as a list of DataTables as you expected.

Comment: Sorry to dig up an old thread but, how do you think it would work if it had to be grouped by both MIVID and another field?

Comment: @RohithShenoyG: You can use anonymous type, something like that: `GroupBy(row => new { Field1 = row.Field<int>('Field1'), Field2 = row.Field<int>('Field2')})`

Comment: @Cuong Le that`s a good one, saved me a lot of time. Just needs to be " instead of ' (not trying to be a wiseguy here, you obviously know that, but probably wrote the "multiple-field comment" straight here).

Comment: @śmiglidigli: I am not sure that I understand what you meant, please could you explain more

Comment: I am just saying you're using a `'Fieldx'` notation, which will not compile, instead of `"Fieldx"` in the comment you added about multiple fields.

Comment: Before I can even ask i found this... Awesome! Thanks. +1. How can I now split each result into another separated list by column?

Comment: can you please look into one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688229/how-to-split-data-table-into-multiple-tables-with-adding-1-minute-delay) related to it?

Comment: Note that `CopyToDataTable()` throws an exception of `The source contains no DataRows` if the query returns no rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable("Data").AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<int>("ParentId") == 1) // ParentId == 1
    .Where(r => r.Field<int>("Id") > 3) // Id > 3
    .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Name").Contains("L")) // Name contains L
    .OrderBy(r => r.Field<int>("Id")) // Order by Id
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: can you please look into one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688229/how-to-split-data-table-into-multiple-tables-with-adding-1-minute-delay) related to it?