# Splitting a Datatable based on Column value

Tags: c#, list, datatable

I have a datatable containing a Bool(bit) Column.

```
  a         b
------    ------ 
  1         10
  0         20
  1         30
  0         20
  1         10
```

I wish to split this into 2 independently sortable datatables based on this value (column a)

I've had a look and found an old question:

[Split a DataTable into 2 or more DataTables based on Column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740353/split-a-datatable-into-2-or-more-datatables-based-on-column-value)

Which gave this:

```
List<DataTable> result = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(row => row.Field<Boolean>("a"))
        .Select(g => g.CopyToDataTable())
        .ToList();
```

But the result isn't a list of datatables I can refer to using `result[0]` and `result[1]` Like I'd expected.

When I hit `result[1]` I get:

> "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size
>   of the collection. Parameter name: index"

I'd add a comment to ask but the thread is well over 2 years old and I'm afraid I'd not get a response.

Can anyone advise of a way to achieve what I'm needing either using this code or something fresh?

Comment: It's not clear why the approach you have shown doesn't work. The result _is_ a `List<DataTable>`. So the first table is `result[0]` and the second table is `result[1]`. It never contains more than two tables.

Comment: Do you mean the order of the tables is not correct - you could order the linq query.

Comment: I mean when I try to access results[0] I get the expected shortened list of results. When I hit results [1] I get "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

Comment: @Spitfire2k6: you get that exception only if the list contains only one table and that is the case if the rows have all the same column-a-value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering `dt` datatable has all the records including both the columns, you can create two `DataView` with your filter condition like

```
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query =
    from data in dt.AsEnumerable()
    where data.Field<bool>("a") == true 
    select data;

DataView view1 = query.AsDataView();



EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query1 =
    from data in dt.AsEnumerable()
    where data.Field<bool>("a") == false 
    select data;

DataView view2 = query1.AsDataView();
```

Comment: Now that's what I call an answer! Cheers bud :D

Comment: I have one datatable and would like to split in half by the number of columns. Please help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271259/how-to-split-a-datatable-in-two-separate-by-columns

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge, have posted an answer in your question thread. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your result *is* a `List<DataTable>`. So the first table is `result[0]` and the second table is `result[1]`. It never contains more than two tables.

It can contain

- 0 tables if the source-table was empty
- 1 table if all had the same value or
- 2 tables if both values were contained.

From your comment:

> When I try to access results[0] I get the expected shortened list of
>   results. When I hit results [1] I get "Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
>   index"

You get that exception if the list contains only one table and that is only the case if the rows have all the same column-a-value(f.e. all have 1).

But you could use another approach if you want. This uses a `Lookup<TKey, TValue>`:

```
var aColLookup= myDataTable.AsEnumerable().ToLookup(row => row.Field<int>("a"));

DataTable trueTable = myDataTable.Clone();
DataTable falseTable = myDataTable.Clone();
if(aColLookup[1].Any())
    trueTable = aColLookup[1].CopyToDataTable();
if (aColLookup[0].Any())
    falseTable = aColLookup[0].CopyToDataTable();
```

I have to use `Clone`(creates an empty table with the same columns) and the `Any`-check because `CopyToDataTable` throws an exception if the sequence contains no rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Globals.Productsdt = Pfdt.AsEnumerable()
                                            .Where(r => r.Field<string>("basecurve") == PFlist[j].PFBC.ToString())
                                            .Where(r => r.Field<string>("diameter") == PFlist[j].PFDM.ToString())
                                            .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Note that `CopyToDataTable()` throws an exception of `The source contains no DataRows` if the query returns no rows.