# how to DataTable split into mutiple datatables c#

Tags: c#, datatable

```
Gender      Age    Category
--------------------------------
Male     |  10     |   2
Female   |  15     |   1
Trans    |  13     |   3
Female   |  10     |   1
Male     |  20     |   2
```

i have a datatable with above values. Male CategoryId is 2.  in above table there are total 2 Males rows. based on Category, merged two rows and divide into a seperate datatable.

My required output is :-

Datatable 1

```
Gender      Age    Category
--------------------------------
Male     |  10     |   2
Male     |  20     |   2
```

DataTable 2

```
Gender      Age    Category
--------------------------------
Female   |  15     |   1
Female   |  10     |   1
```

DataTable 3

```
Gender      Age    Category
--------------------------------
Trans    |  13     |   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
List<DataTable> result = DTHead.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(row => row.Field<DataType>("Category"))
            .Select(g => g.CopyToDataTable())
            .ToList();
```

For more details please check this post:[Split Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740353/split-a-datatable-into-2-or-more-datatables-based-on-column-value)

Answer (score 2):

```
var view = sourceDataTable.DefaultView;

view.RowFilter = "Category = 2";
var maleDataTable = view.ToTable();

view.RowFilter = "Category = 1";
var femaleDataTable = view.ToTable();

view.RowFilter = "Category = 3";
var transDataTable = view.ToTable();
```

Comment: This is probably the cleanest way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

See following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication48
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Gender", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Male", 10, 2});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Female", 15, 1});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Trans", 13, 3});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Female", 10, 1});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Male", 20, 2});

            DataTable dt1 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Gender") == "Male").CopyToDataTable();
            DataTable dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Gender") == "Feale").CopyToDataTable();
            DataTable dt3 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Gender") == "Trans").CopyToDataTable();


        }

    }

}
```

---

Here is a more generic solution that get every type in a column :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication48
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Gender", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Male", 10, 2 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Female", 15, 1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Trans", 13, 3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Female", 10, 1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Male", 20, 2 });

            //updated code
            string[] rowNames = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Gender")).Distinct().ToArray();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            foreach (string gender in rowNames)
            {
                DataTable newDt = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Gender") == gender).CopyToDataTable();
                newDt.TableName = gender;
                ds.Tables.Add(newDt);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: but my dataTable is dynamic. some times getting more rows with different values.

Comment: Code will work with any number of rows.  I just posted sample data to test code.